# Add .0D0 to end of numbers in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, fortran

I have a code that I'd like translate from another language to Fortran.  The code has a large numbered vector--`V(n)`--as well as both numerous variables named tn (where n is a one- to four-digit number) and numerous real numbers currently written as integers.  In order to have Fortran treat the integers as doubles I would like to add `.0D0` to the end of every integer.

So if I have an expression like:

```
V(1000) = t434 * 45/7 + 1296 * t18
```

I'd like Vim to change it to:

```
V(1000) = t434 * 45.0D0/7.0D0 + 1296.0D0 * t18
```

I've been trying to use negative look behind to ignore expressions starting with `t` or `V(`, and look ahead or ze to find the end of the numbers, but I've had no luck.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
V(1000) = t434 * 45/7 + 1296 * t18
```

Command:

```
:%s/\(\(t\|V(\)\d*\)\@<!\(\d\+\)\d\@!/\3.0D0/g
```

Result:

```
V(1000) = t434 * 45.0D0/7.0D0 + 1296.0D0 * t18
```

The command is:

```
:%s/                  search/replace on every line

  \(\(t\|V(\)\d*\)    t or V(, followed by no or more numbers
                      otherwise it matches 34 in  t434

  \@<!                negative lookbehind
                      to block numbers starting with t or V(

  \(\d\+\)            a run of digits - the bit we care about

  \d\@!               negative lookahead more digits,
                      otherwise it matches 10 in 1000

/                     replace part of the search/replace

    \3                match group 3 has the number we care about
    .0D0              the text you want to add

/g                    global flag, apply many times in a line
```